# AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '_dom'

Tags: python, attributes

I'm testing ebaysdk Python library that lets you connect to ebay. Now I'm trying examples from: https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/

So far I got stuck at this example:

```
from ebaysdk.shopping import Connection as Shopping
shopping = Shopping(domain="svcs.sandbox.ebay.com", config_file="ebay.yaml")
response = shopping.execute('FindPopularItems',
           {'QueryKeywords': 'Python'})
print response.disct()
```

When I run it. It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ebay-test.py", line 13, in <module>
    {'QueryKeywords': 'Python'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 123, in execute
    self.error_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 193, in error_check
    estr = self.error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/connection.py", line 305, in error
    error_array.extend(self._get_resp_body_errors())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/shopping/__init__.py", line 188, in _get_resp_body_errors
    dom = self.response.dom()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/response.py", line 229, in dom
    return self._dom
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ebaysdk-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/ebaysdk/response.py", line 216, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._obj, name)
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute '_dom'
```

Am I missing something here or it could be some kind of bug in library?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a config file? I had a lot of problems getting started with this SDK. To get the yaml config file to work, I had to specify the directory that it was in. So in your example, it would be:

```
shopping = Shopping(domain="svcs.sandbox.ebay.com", config_file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'ebay.yaml'))
```

You should also be able to specify debug=true in your `Shopping()` declaration as in `Shopping(debug=True)`.

Make sure if you have not, to specify your APP_ID and other necessary values in the config file.

Comment: Yes I have specified config file and all other parameters. The thing is it only gives this message when I call Connection from shopping. From other like trading, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong domain, it should be `open.api.sandbox.ebay.com`. See this page on the [ebaysdk github](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/issues/84).